# Не работает SQL запрос на две таблицы

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Я использую PDO. Полученный результат я вывожу через `foreach`.
Запрос не срабатывает, ошибка 500, и вот что в логах: `Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetchAll() on boolean`

Как я только не пытался изменить запрос — все равно такая-же фигня. Мистика какая-то.

```
$query = $db->query("

    SELECT a.".aconfig::ADATA_ID.", 
           a.".aconfig::ADATA_NAME.", 
           a.".aconfig::ADATA_LEVEL."
    FROM ".aconfig::TABLE_ADATA." a
    JOIN ".aconfig::TABLE_AINT." b
    WHERE b.".aconfig::AINT_ASTATUS." = '0'
    ORDER BY a.".aconfig::ADATA_LEVEL." DESC LIMIT 10

")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($query as $out) {

     $outJSON['success'][] = array(

           "id"        => $out[aconfig::ADATA_ID],
           "nick"      => $out[aconfig::ADATA_NAME],
           "level"     => $out[aconfig::ADATA_LEVEL]

     );

}
```

Comment: Приложите код с PHP.

Comment: @ZhukovRoman обновил.

Comment: Код коннекта к БД приложите

Comment: Простой запрос типа `SELECT * FROM your_table` работает? Если нет, проблема в подключении, если да - проблема в неверном запросе..... например если сделать `echo Ваша_строка_запроса` - можно посмотреть, что скармливается

Comment: @АлексейШиманский простой запрос то работает. Мистика какая-то.

Comment: На select запрос pdo::query ответит false только в том глупом случае, когда pdo запрещено бросать нормальные исключения. Измените `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE` в адекватный `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` и смотрите, с чем именно не согласна СУБД. Так гадать не имеет смысла.

Comment: @РоманКотов значит проблема в запросе.... выведи его просто через echo и исполни его в любой среде SQL или включи ошибки и смотри в них на что ругается и в общем в любом случае "чистый" запрос надо смотреть... может там что-то не подставилось или подставляется строка, не помещенная в кавычки

Comment: @Мелкий я уже это сделал. И в чем прикол, с ORDER выдает ошибку: (Errcode: 28) якобы нет места. Как только убираю с запроса ORDER — все нормально, правда не сортирует.

Comment: А сколько места доступно для filesort в MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

У вас не хватает места для сортировки данных. Выхода два:

1) Очистить место на том диске, где располагаются временные файлы

2) Использовать другой диск для временных файлов.

Comment: Юзер самоуничтожился)

Comment: уход по "английски" ))